# Drag & Drop, dropping blocked by his children, how to avoid that?

Tags: drag-and-drop, parent-child, godot, gdscript

Gonna try to be the more concise & clear possible.

Making a game, while I do use Drag & drop, wanna drop on a "panel", and add it to a list in that same panel. Well it already works actually. But not well.

The problem come that, **I can only drop it on place where that "panel" doesn't have his children. So on empty place onto that panel. And I want it to be on the entire list, empty place or not.**

So tried to do a `children_has_point()` to check while `can_drop_data()` is running, but seems the whole source of that problems is because `can_drop_data()` doesn't trigger if the draggable is over the childrens.
So tried to try things with `mouse_filter` from the parent, and it doesn't seems to affect `can_drop_data()` neither.

So what can I do to fix/make it work the way I intend to ?

(By the way, I know that one of the solution would be to literraly create a Rect2 or something similar on top of that whole list panel to let know the `can_drop_data()` that it can be dropped on the whole list, but that seems more bothersome to do, trying to see if they aren't a better solution ?)

Well I hope this is not too messy and unclear question, prob not, but well I tried what I can. And this last line prob gonna get deleted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By the way, I know that one of the solution would be to literraly create a Rect2 or something similar on top of that whole list panel to let know the can_drop_data() that it can be dropped on the whole list

Having a `Control` (e.g. a `Panel`) does not have to be much trouble, in particular: You do not have to create it on demand, instead you can having it always there, and bring it to top or push it to the bottom.

---

I believe the issue is that children are taking mouse input. In this case it should be sufficient to set `mouse_filter` to `MOUSE_FILTER_PASS` (so if they don't handle the input it propagates to the parent) or to `MOUSE_FILTER_IGNORE` (so they don't take any mouse input).

However, if always having that setting causes other problems, you would have to consider changing them in runtime. I'm going to suggest to add the `Control`s you need to modify in runtime to a node group, to make that code simpler.

Comment: For the Control on top that parent, thought that would the interactions with it that would be bothersome, cuz in a way, those same childrens that block are also clickable and draggable... But...

Comment: But seems I misunderstood how `mouse_filter` worked, thought the `mouse_filter` parent would "pass" the click to it's childrens... not that the `MOUSE_FILTER_PASS` would pass it to Control with less Z-index... my bad. And thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @SaltChaos I've seen other people expressing that they expected it to work differently. However, it is [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling).